# How to convert timestamp type to Unix time in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

I hava a timestamp type, like x = 2019.06.24T09:05:43.478, how to covert it to Unix time?

x =  2019.06.24T09:05:43.478

Answer (score 0):

A timestamp in DolphinDB is represented by Unix time internally. Thus, you can simply use `long` function to convert.

```
long(x)

1561367143478
```